Simple way to run the same code on different sets of variables, and for each, store the results in a readable format
Context :
Hi, I'm a mechanical engineer trying to use Jupyter (or similar code based solution) to run mechanical calculus when they are to complex to be understood in Excel formulas. The problem araise when trying to reuse the code for different scenarios, which implies some variable changes - like material properties, forces and so on.
Question :
Does a simple solution (for non programmer) exist to run the same code on multiple sets of variables, store the calculus output of each in a way which makes it easy to read, compare analyse the different cases ?
Maybe Python is not the best tool for this ?
Details :
I've tried to use an Excel file as the input source for the variables suseptible to be changed, then making the program grab their value from it. Each Excel row represente a different scenario, and the program would write the calculs outputs at the end of each row.
I'm not convinced by the method because the "links" between the two files needs to be hardcoded, or I need to write complex functions to automate the process, which is too much for me.

You can use Python to process multiple files with the same code, and then have some other Python code that 'groups' the results together for easy comparison.

Yes, but I need to write the function to import and export the values from the files to the program variable myself ? No library exist to help me on that ?
Maybe the Pyton implementation in Excel could do the trick. It could offer a solution for a"graphical way" to input and review multiple senarios and allow the use python to write the calculation, making it readable and more powerfull for graphs and such. I will give it a try.

Yes you would need some code to read the CSV data, run the analysis, and then save the results as tables and graphs. It would mostly be done using the pandas library for data handling and matplotlib for visualisation. If you are able to share the code and sample data I can code up a demonstration.

I have simplified the program as much as I could, you will find :

MyLibrary : Library of functions I use in multiple places
MainCalculus.py : The file dedicated to run a specific calculus
*Variables.xlsx : Excel file where the variables for each calculus senario are stored

Also, I have not translated the calculus function because it's not the focus here
https://www.dropbox.com/t/2VxMVWzOI1oal2RV

The code below produces these outputs:
Visualise Variables.xlsx:

Final results (also saved to final_table.csv):

The main part is this block:
results_df = (
    variables_df.apply(
        lambda row_: ContrainteCylindrePressionInterne(row_.InternalRadius, row_.ExternalRadius, row_.InternalPressure),
        axis=1,
        result_type='expand'
    )
    .set_axis(
        ['ContraintRadiale', 'ContrainteCirconferencielle', 'ContrainteLongitudinale'],
        axis='columns'
    )
)

The .apply(<function>, axis=1) puts each row (axis=1) through <function>. Since <function> returns 3 numbers in this case, I use result_type='expand' to expand the results into 3 columns.
<function> needs to accept a Series object. So I wrapped your function ContrainteCylindrePressionInterne in another function using the lambda operator.
lambda row_: ContrainteCylindrePressionInterne(row_.InternalRadius, ...)

This defines a function that that takes row_ data and processes it using your function. It is equivalent to defining a regular function:
def calc_row(row_series):
    return ContrainteCylindrePressionInterne(row_series.InternalRadius, ...)

...
variables_df.apply(calc_row, axis=1, ...)

The .set_axis renames the 3 columns.

#Imports
import pandas as pd

#
# Load and visualise variables.xlsx
#
#Drop the first row as it is not needed
variables_df = pd.read_excel('Variables.xlsx').iloc[1:]

#View the data
display(variables_df)

#View the values for each case
variables_df.plot.bar(x='NameRow', figsize=(7, 1.5), subplots=True, layout=(1, 3), xlabel='', legend=False);

#
# Apply computation to table
#
def ContrainteCylindrePressionInterne(RayonInterieur, RayonExterieur, PressionInterne, RayonPositionCalculContrainte=None, CylindreEstOuvert=False):
    if RayonPositionCalculContrainte is not None:
        if RayonPositionCalculContrainte < RayonInterieur or RayonPositionCalculContrainte > RayonExterieur:
            raise ValueError("RayonPositionCalculContrainte doit être compris entre RayonInterieur et RayonExtérieur")
    else:
        RayonPositionCalculContrainte = RayonInterieur

    ContrainteRadiale = (
        RayonInterieur**2 * PressionInterne
        / (RayonExterieur**2 - RayonInterieur**2)
        * (1 - RayonExterieur**2 / RayonPositionCalculContrainte**2)
    )
    
    ContrainteCirconferencielle = (
        RayonInterieur**2 * PressionInterne
        / (RayonExterieur**2 - RayonInterieur**2)
        * (1 + RayonExterieur**2 / RayonPositionCalculContrainte**2)
    )

    if not CylindreEstOuvert:
        ContrainteLongitudinale = RayonInterieur**2 * PressionInterne / (RayonExterieur**2 - RayonInterieur**2)
    else:
        ContrainteLongitudinale = 0

    return ContrainteRadiale, ContrainteCirconferencielle, ContrainteLongitudinale

#Apply function to each row and put into results_df
results_df = (
    variables_df.apply(
        lambda row_: ContrainteCylindrePressionInterne(row_.InternalRadius, row_.ExternalRadius, row_.InternalPressure),
        axis=1,
        result_type='expand'
    )
    .set_axis(
        ['ContraintRadiale', 'ContrainteCirconferencielle', 'ContrainteLongitudinale'],
        axis='columns'
    )
)

#Join (on index) with original table
final_df = variables_df.join(results_df)

display(final_df)

#Visualise results
(
    final_df
    [['NameRow', 'ContraintRadiale', 'ContrainteCirconferencielle', 'ContrainteLongitudinale']]
    .plot.bar(x='NameRow', subplots=True, layout=(1, 3), figsize=(8, 2), xlabel='', legend=False)
);

#Save table
final_df.to_csv('final_table.csv')


That's a lesson of simplicity ! It's exactly what I needed, thank you.
I should take more time to read documentation ...
Short answer :
Run a function for each row/column with df.apply

May I ask you to explain why you used lambda here ? I think it can be part of the struggle for beginners.

Sure. I have added explanatory points to the answer.
